# Trouble passing petite-vue state to subcomponent and getting undefined in Astro

Tags: astrojs, petite-vue

- astro: 4.0.7
- petite-vue: 0.4.1

I'm attempting to pass the state (name) managed by petite-vue in my `index.astro` to `ShowImg.astro` for displaying images.

However, I'm running into an undefined problem.

Interestingly, when I print the value of 'name' in `ShowImg.astro`, it does have a value ('dog').

In the `index.astro`, I import ShowImg and pass the petite-vue state:

```
// index.astro
---
import ShowImg from './ShowImg.astro'
---

<div class=" text-gray-50 bg-black">
    <div id="app">
        <ShowImg name="{{store.name}}" />
    </div>
</div>

<script>
import { createApp, reactive } from 'petite-vue';

interface Data {
    name: string;
    getImg: () => string;
}

const store = reactive<Data>({
    name: 'dog',
 });

createApp({
    store
}).mount('#app');
</script>
```

Here is the relevant code from ShowImg.astro:

```
// ShowImg.astro
---
import { Image } from 'astro:assets';
import dog from '../assets/dog.jpg';
import cat from '../assets/cat.jpg';

const { name } = Astro.props;

const imgObj: Record<string, ImageMetadata> = {
  'dog': dog,
  'cat': cat
}
---

<!-- Successfully displays image -->
<Image src={imgObj['dog']} alt="image of dog or cat">

<!-- Results in undefined -->
<Image src={imgObj[name]} alt="image of dog or cat">

<!-- Successfully prints 'dog' -->
<div>
  {name}
</div>
```

How can I address this issue and successfully access petite-vue state values within `imgObj` in the subcomponent?

Thanks!!

I've tried the following:

```
<!-- Successfully displays image -->
<Image src={imgObj['dog']} alt="image of dog or cat">

<!-- Results in undefined -->
<Image src={imgObj[name]} alt="image of dog or cat">
```

Comment: Should that be `imgObj[store.name]` instead of `imgObj[name]`?